# Trouble running an Observer Pattern example

Tags: javascript, debugging, design-patterns, observer-pattern, observers

I am trying to reproduce the Observer Pattern example given in the book [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript) but I get this error in the `extend` function:

[image]

I am using the code in the book starting below this line:

> First, let's model the list of dependent Observers a subject may have:

I have set up the code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cm5a62jb/) and I'd like to understand why I'm getting the error.

Comment: Did I answer the question to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the reported error in your question is that the first argument to `extend()` is not a valid object.

When I run your jsFiddle, it reports that `Observer is not defined`.

If the `Observer()` pattern should be parallel to the `Subject()` pattern, then you are missing this piece of code:

```
function Observer() {
  this.observers = new ObserverList();
}
```

Or, perhaps you just need to change:

```
extend( new Observer(), check );
```

to:

```
extend( new ObserverList(), check );
```

So that it uses the code you show for `ObserverList()`.

---

In fact, when I press the button in your jsFiddle, the error that occurs is `Uncaught ReferenceError: Observer is not defined` which further confirms the above.

And, when I apply that change, the code seems to run here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8xmu1mcg/, though I don't know exactly what it's supposed to do, but it adds a checkbox and there are no errors.

Comment: The best example in JavaScript that I can think of is the node.js EventEmitter class.

You can check the code out here: https://github.com/Wolfy87/EventEmitter/blob/master/EventEmitter.js

Comment: @DuncanFinney - Good example.  I think the EventEmitter object in node.js is one of the most useful utility objects they have and probably the most used for inheritance or mixin in the whole node library.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that you have neglected to define `Observer`. After adding the function definition, the fiddle works:

http://jsfiddle.net/cm5a62jb/1/

```js
// The Observer
function Observer(){
  this.update = function(){
    // ...
  };
}

function ObserverList(){
  this.observerList = [];
}
 
ObserverList.prototype.add = function( obj ){
  return this.observerList.push( obj );
};
 
ObserverList.prototype.count = function(){
  return this.observerList.length;
};
 
ObserverList.prototype.get = function( index ){
  if( index > -1 && index < this.observerList.length ){
    return this.observerList[ index ];
  }
};
 
ObserverList.prototype.indexOf = function( obj, startIndex ){
  var i = startIndex;
 
  while( i < this.observerList.length ){
    if( this.observerList[i] === obj ){
      return i;
    }
    i++;
  }
 
  return -1;
};
 
ObserverList.prototype.removeAt = function( index ){
  this.observerList.splice( index, 1 );
};

function Subject(){
  this.observers = new ObserverList();
}
 
Subject.prototype.addObserver = function( observer ){
  this.observers.add( observer );
};
 
Subject.prototype.removeObserver = function( observer ){
  this.observers.removeAt( this.observers.indexOf( observer, 0 ) );
};
 
Subject.prototype.notify = function( context ){
  var observerCount = this.observers.count();
  for(var i=0; i < observerCount; i++){
    this.observers.get(i).update( context );
  }
};

// Extend an object with an extension
function extend( extension, obj ){
  for ( var key in extension ){
    obj[key] = extension[key];
  }
}
 
// References to our DOM elements
 
var controlCheckbox = document.getElementById( "mainCheckbox" ),
  addBtn = document.getElementById( "addNewObserver" ),
  container = document.getElementById( "observersContainer" );
 
 
// Concrete Subject
 
// Extend the controlling checkbox with the Subject class
extend( new Subject(), controlCheckbox );
 
// Clicking the checkbox will trigger notifications to its observers
controlCheckbox.onclick = function(){
  controlCheckbox.notify( controlCheckbox.checked );
};
 
addBtn.onclick = addNewObserver;
 
// Concrete Observer
 
function addNewObserver(){
 
  // Create a new checkbox to be added
  var check = document.createElement( "input" );
  check.type = "checkbox";
 
  // Extend the checkbox with the Observer class
  extend( new Observer(), check );
 
  // Override with custom update behaviour
  check.update = function( value ){
    this.checked = value;
  };
 
  // Add the new observer to our list of observers
  // for our main subject
  controlCheckbox.addObserver( check );
 
  // Append the item to the container
  container.appendChild( check );
}
```

```html
<button id="addNewObserver">Add New Observer checkbox</button>
<input id="mainCheckbox" type="checkbox"/>
<div id="observersContainer"></div>
```